# Understanding javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm fairly new to JavaScript, and I'm not sure I fully understand what's going on with the code snippet below:

```
if ($(".filter-icon").length == 0)
  return;
```

So I understand the `if` statement, but the part that I don't fully understand is the `$(".filter-icon").length`. After going through the documentation I'm a bit confused. How is `$(".filter-icon")` an array? I thought it was just anything that had a `filter-icon` class associated with it. How can you get the length of that?

I apologize for the basic question, but I'm very confused by this and it's hard to google with punctuation.

Comment: It's a *collection* that contains all elements that have a `filter-icon` class, yes. Such a collection object can have a `.length`.

Comment: Can you be more accurate about what you believe an "*anything that had a class*" is? It might help us with clearing your (mis)understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This: `$(".filter-icon")` — is a **jQuery** function call. The returned value is in fact *not* an array, but it *does* have a `length` property. The `length` of the result of that function call is a count of the number of elements in the DOM that matched the selector.

The point of that code is to check whether there are any elements in a DOM that have the class "filter-icon".

It's not that uncommon in JavaScript programming to run into things that *appear* to be arrays, but which really aren't. Happily, many of the built-in functions for real arrays are fairly loose about what they'll accept, so you can quite often use native array functions to do interesting things with objects that just sort-of pretend to be real arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(".filter-icon").length == 0)
  return;
```

This will check for all the elements which are having class as `filter-icon`. If it does not find any, it will return the counter.

An example from jquery website, to count the no. of divs :

```
$( document.body )
  .click(function() {
    $( document.body ).append( $( "<div>" ) );
    var n = $( "div" ).length;
    $( "span" ).text( "There are " + n + " divs." +
      "Click to add more.");
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

All four answers are correct.  The $(".filter-icon") construct is JQuery, searching the DOM for all elements with a class="filter-icon" attribute.  It will return 0 or more elements, and the .length == 0 test determines if there were no matches.

In essence,

If there are no HTML tags with class="filter-icon", then simply return.

Comment: Technically the answers that say the return value is an array are not 100% correct, since it's not an array.

Answer (score -1):

So, the $ is jQuery. The $() is a function call, and that function returns a jQuery object, which acts like an array.

It would be easier to see in action if the code looked like this:

```
    var matches = $(".filter-icon");
    if (matches.length == 0)
        return;
```

The way that the $() function works, is it selects elements from the HTML page that match the css selection, and returns the elements as a jQuery object that behaves like an array.

Since the return behaves as an array, you can string it together as $(".filter-icon").length, and in fact that is the more common way to write it.

Even if you use jQuery to select some HTML elements that only appear once on the page, such as $("#myId"), which, as an ID would only occur once on the page, you'll still get back an indexable array object, it just will have one item.

Answer (score -2):

As said by @Pointy, `$` is a jQuery function. However, it returns an array, which has a property `length`.